# Rails bootstrap_form_for: text_area is automatically hidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I made a very simple form using bootstrap_form_for:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@ad) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.text_field :image %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_id %>   
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

However, in the text_area for the 'body' field, this is the html generated:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="ad_body">Body</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="ad[body]" id="ad_body" style="display: none !important;"></textarea>
</div>
```

For some reason, it's set to display:none. I searched anywhere in the application and couldn't find a place I set it to display:none.

Any clue?

I'm using Ruby 2.2.3 and Rails 4.2.4.

Comment: Do you use any JS scripts or jQuery plugins? Try disabling them one by one and see who's hiding the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue, I managed to fix it just by changing the column name from `body` to `ad_body`. It's just that probably `body` is a protected term.